# tabularray vertical aligment of cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularray

I am starting to figure out how to use tabularray in LaTex, but now I am not figuring out how to set my table text to be vertically centered. Here is my minimum example of a working table (but the text of the cells aren't vertically aligned):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \small
\caption{As 32 heurísticas propostas para avaliação de jogos educacionais para aprendizado da Língua Japonesa.},
\label {tab:tabela4}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, %% isso aqui é pra botar linhas entre as células 
                  colsep=4pt, %% adicionar um esacinho entre colunas da tabela
                  colspec = {X[c] c 
                             X[2, c] X[2, cmd=\RaggedRight]},
                  rows = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont},
                  rowhead = 2}
\SetCell[r=3]{c} Equilíbrio de Desafio e Habilidade
    & 1 & Conteúdo ensinado é dividido em níveis/fases de dificuldade gradualmente incremental, e com níveis adequados de conteúdo a ser introduzido e conteúdos revisado?  
        & Conteúdo exercitado é dividido em categorias, porém, categorias podem conter até 59 novas palavras para aprender.            \\
    & 2 & Apresenta novidades à jogatina ao refazer níveis de jogo?
        & Modo treino não apresenta novidades ao refazer treinos; os modos competitivos oferecem quatro itens de jogo a serem usados durante uma partida, sendo aleatoriamente oferecidos durante um duelo. O uso desses itens traz aleatoriedade às partidas, proporcionando novas experiências.          \\
    & 3 & Utiliza algoritmos para equilibrar partidas contra Inteligências Artificiais (IAs) e contra jogadores?    
        & Em partidas contra jogadores, jogadores podem duelar contra oponentes com classificações similares em um ranking global do jogo, calculado a partir da quantidade de vitórias e derrotas de jogadores. O modo treino não oferece partidas contra IAs, porém permite que o jogador treine os kanjis que erra com mais frequência. \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The example you show in your question is missing the `ragged2e` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `valign=m` option to vertically centre your cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \small
\caption{As 32 heurísticas propostas para avaliação de jogos educacionais para aprendizado da Língua Japonesa.},
\label {tab:tabela4}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, %% isso aqui é pra botar linhas entre as células 
                  colsep=4pt, %% adicionar um esacinho entre colunas da tabela
                  colspec = {X[c] c 
                             X[2, c] X[2, cmd=\RaggedRight]},
                  rows = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont},
                  rowhead = 2,
                  cells={valign=m}
                  }
\SetCell[r=3]{c} Equilíbrio de Desafio e Habilidade
    & 1 & Conteúdo ensinado é dividido em níveis/fases de dificuldade gradualmente incremental, e com níveis adequados de conteúdo a ser introduzido e conteúdos revisado?  
        & Conteúdo exercitado é dividido em categorias, porém, categorias podem conter até 59 novas palavras para aprender.            \\
    & 2 & Apresenta novidades à jogatina ao refazer níveis de jogo?
        & Modo treino não apresenta novidades ao refazer treinos; os modos competitivos oferecem quatro itens de jogo a serem usados durante uma partida, sendo aleatoriamente oferecidos durante um duelo. O uso desses itens traz aleatoriedade às partidas, proporcionando novas experiências.          \\
    & 3 & Utiliza algoritmos para equilibrar partidas contra Inteligências Artificiais (IAs) e contra jogadores?    
        & Em partidas contra jogadores, jogadores podem duelar contra oponentes com classificações similares em um ranking global do jogo, calculado a partir da quantidade de vitórias e derrotas de jogadores. O modo treino não oferece partidas contra IAs, porém permite que o jogador treine os kanjis que erra com mais frequência. \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: many thanks! It works! just one more question: is it possible for me to reduce even more of the font size, besides using font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont ?

Comment: @FabioPhillip You could use a smaller font, e.g. try `\tiny` for an extreme.